# Javascript ¿Que es lo que esta mal?

Tags: javascript

He escrito este código y salvo el encabezado, no sale nada mas. ¿Donde esta el /los fallos?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<body> 
<h2>JavaScript document.write & document.getElementById.innerHTML Methods</h2>

<p id="output1" ></p> 
<p id="output2" ></p> 

<script>
var myObj = [firsname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe'];
document.write(" " + myObj);
document.write("hello world");
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "" + myObj;
document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "Hello World";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: var myObj = [firsname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe']; lo haces así var myObj = [{firsname : 'John'}, {lastname : 'Doe'}]; o así => var myObj = {firsname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe'};

Answer (score 4):

La sintaxis de tu objeto esta mal, para crear objetos se usan `{` y no `[`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<body> 
<h2>JavaScript document.write & document.getElementById.innerHTML Methods</h2>

<p id="output1" ></p> 
<p id="output2" ></p> 

<script>
var myObj = {firsname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe'};
document.write(" " + myObj);
document.write("hello world");
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "" + myObj;
document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "Hello World";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Anotado. Para que no me de Object Object como resultado, aplico también la sugerencia de Rodrihgo.

Answer (score -1):

Para añadir, estas incluyendo un objeto dentro del DOM,
debes acceder al atributo de cada objeto para que sea visible la info que contiene, ahi:

```
<script>
var myObj = [firsname : 'John', lastname : 'Doe'];
```

.

```
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "" + myObj.firsname +" - "+ myObj.lastname;
```

...

Comment: Gracias anotado.